# Make esttab print different parentheses in different columns

Tags: stata

How would I go about to get `esttab` use square brackets around the standard errors in the third column of the regression table below while still using regular parentheses in the second?

```
. eststo clear

. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
(est1 stored)

. eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg foreign
(est2 stored)

. esttab, cells(b se(par(( )))

--------------------------------------
                      (1)          (2)
                    price        price
                     b/se         b/se
--------------------------------------
weight           1.746559     3.464706
               (.6413538)    (.630749)
mpg             -49.51222      21.8536
               (86.15604)   (74.22114)
foreign                        3673.06
                            (683.9783)
_cons            1946.069    -5853.696
                (3597.05)   (3376.987)
--------------------------------------
N                      74           74
--------------------------------------
```

To be clear, what I would like is to get a table like the one below.

```
--------------------------------------
                      (1)          (2)
                    price        price
                     b/se         b/se
--------------------------------------
weight           1.746559     3.464706
               (.6413538)    [.630749]
mpg             -49.51222      21.8536
               (86.15604)   [74.22114]
foreign                        3673.06
                            [683.9783]
_cons            1946.069    -5853.696
                (3597.05)   [3376.987]
--------------------------------------
N                      74           74
--------------------------------------
```